increase degradation of cow dung in order to convert it into ready to use manure?
Contex : some of the articles and papers says to mix curd water (I am aware about most of the western part use pasteurized milk but in India it is very easy to get milk in natural form) with the dried cow dung powder and some of the other things and let it sit in dark place for 1-2 months in order to convert into into well-rotted manure.
Some articles also suggest to mix a day (or two) old rice water.
More or less all of this focused to add Lactiplantibacillus into the mix and let them breakkdown (bacterial fermentation) the dung.
Question : What else could be done to increase the decomposing process and convert dung in to a well-rotted and safe manure?

Standard aerobic composting (which has a LOT of published literature) will get the job done effectively - there are many ways to do that which vary with the scale of the operation.

i am open to consider any reasonable suggestion so  please any thing that can reduce the time period as much as 1 to 2 weeks will be a lot.

Bacterial fermentation acidifies and preserves the substrate, so I am assuming that is a temporary state on the way to fully composted manure, not the end point.
In no particular order, the Speed of Compost is influenced by:

Temperature
The compost needs to be an appropriate temperature to facilitate the
life doing the composting.  As composting is exothermic, this will
often maintain itself.  40°C-65°C is a good target.

Moisture
Microbes need enough moisture to survive and move in the pile, but no
so much that they can't get air too.  Approximately 50% of the pile
by weight should be water. It should feel like a wrung out sponge in
your hand.

Aeration
The compost pile needs air as well.  This is directly used by the life in the pile and also a way to cast off heat.  Turning it so it stays porous
and 'fluffy' can help. Some folks bury a pipe in the pile and
blow air through it 24/7, which is called 'forced aeration'.

Turning
Turning or mixing the pile will bring new material from the outside
to the center of the pile, and will also aerate it.

Carbon:Nitrogen ratio
A compost pile wants approximately 30 times as much carbon as
nitrogen in the pile by weight.  I do not know what your cattle eat,
but I suspect their manure could do with some extra carbon.  Sawdust,
straw, paper, stuff like that.

pH
Some dainty composting microbes can not tolerate an acidic compost pile.  As in, a pH of 6.5 is too acidic for them.  The pile will moderate this
itself over time if adequately aerated, but managing it yourself can
also help.


From what you have described, I believe adding a carbon source to the manure would be easy and accelerate the process.  Forced aeration would be more difficult, but I think it would hugely accelerate the process.  Some folks claim it can finish compost in 4 weeks or less.

these all are obvious and well known , i want something that  decrease the time drastically to 1-2 week . but thanks for your answer : )

MackM stellar answer! @Rainy sidewalks my anaerobic compost(apartments and stuff) takes 2 years. My granddad(a pretty damn competent farmer)'s manure compost used to take something in the lines of 6 months(low estimate). Bottom line - have patience.

oh man i almost did not see the name :p
